# AngularJS custom directive in the popover redraw

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a button that triggers a popover with a custom directive.
The problem is that on button click the popover is empty, the custom directive stuff only kicks in when I force angular cycle (change data in the input field, etc.)
Once that happens popover gets redrawn with custom directive stuff as expected.

How can I make it so the custom directive gets executed when the popover gets opened?

Some code:

Button - `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" bs-popover="'partials/test.html'"><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i></button>`

partials/test.html - `<itemlist apicall="'attributes'" editable="'false'" selectable="'true'" viewtype="'attributes'" template="partials/itemlist.html"></itemlist>` (itemlist is the custom directive)

itemlist directive -

```
.directive('itemlist', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { apicall: '=', editable: '=', viewtype: '=', selectable: '=' },
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $resource, $timeout, fileReader, apiaddress, $dialog, errormsg) {
            var resource = $resource(apiaddress + $scope.apicall, {}, { update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@Id' } } });
            $scope.apiresource = { list: resource.query() };

            //TODO: See how to only display one.
            toastr.info("Loading...");


        },
        templateUrl: function (tElement, tAttrs) { return tAttrs.template },
        replace: true
    };
})
```

One more thing - the `itemlist` custom directive works in other areas of the app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the resource is retrieving data asynchronously, so resource.query() doesn't guarantee the data being returned synchronously. You can try to change the line to be

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.apiresource = {
        list: resource.query()
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but that's not it. It never gets that far - it seems that the entire `itemlist` directive inside `partials/test.html` doesn't get processed until another angular cycle is forced..